# Stacked bar graph with individual data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a stacked bar graph with the average of the data points while showing individual data points by overlaying them.

A short example of the data frame can be created using the following code:

```
df = data.frame(sample = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"), GFP = c(14, 15, 16, 28, 36, 35), 
                double = c(26, 23, 30, 41, 39, 45), Ab = c(12, 10, 9, 8, 10, 8))
```

Essentially, I have different conditions (condition A or B) which were then observed for different categories of readings (GFP, Ab, or double).  Such data has been generated over three replicates (replicates 1~3).
*The real data I've got has many more conditions, therefore I'd prefer to summarize the data output graphically as much as possible.

My ideal graphical output would be something like the below (generated with PowerPoint):

[image]
The ideal graph would have each stacked bar representing the average (ie, average readings of GFP, double, Ab across repetition 1~3 of condition A stacked on top of each other, which another stack exists of B). Additionally, I'd like to have the actual readings of each repetition shown as a dot (and maybe an error bar, but if that is too complicated, I think we can skip that).

I do not mind having to wrangle the data table, but I would appreciate a method of generating such a graph in R.  Of course, if you have any other advice on how to approach such data representation (ie, if you think it should be made into separate series of graphs instead), I'd welcome that as well.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `separate` to extract the letters and numbers from `sample` so you can plot appropriately. I am not sure how to add the error bars since its unclear where in the data they are coming from. As a recommendation, `facet_wrap` will likely make your plot more readable.

```
set.seed(12345)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(sample = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"), 
                GFP = c(14, 15, 16, 28, 36, 35), 
                double = c(26, 23, 30, 41, 39, 45),
                Ab = c(12, 10, 9, 8, 10, 8))

df2 <- df %>%
  separate(col = "sample", c("letter", "number"), sep="(?<=[A-Z])") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("GFP", "double", "Ab"))
head(df2)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   letter number name   value
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 A      1      GFP       14
#> 2 A      1      double    26
#> 3 A      1      Ab        12
#> 4 A      2      GFP       15
#> 5 A      2      double    23
#> 6 A      2      Ab        10

# attempt at replication
ggplot(df2, aes(x = letter, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_jitter(aes(y = value, shape = number), size = 3, alpha = .75, width = .25)

# recommendation
#ggplot(df2, aes(x = letter, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  #geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  #geom_jitter(aes(y = value, shape = number), size = 3, alpha = .75, width = .25) +
  #facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

EDIT: Added additional alternative plot below so the blue area of the A bar equals the mean (in this dataframe, 15).

```
# alternative plot
df3 <- df %>%
  separate(col = "sample", c("letter", "number"), sep="(?<=[A-Z])") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("GFP", "double", "Ab")) %>%
  group_by(letter, name) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(value)) %>%
  filter(number == "1") %>%
  select(-c(number, value))
  
ggplot(df3, aes(x = letter, y = mean, fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(y = mean, shape = name), size = 3, alpha = .75, width = .25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your strategy!  I actually tried to make stacked bars by reordering the format of the data frame to something close to what you suggest but in this case, I realized that the bar graph adds up all of the replicates(ie, the blue area of A is not average of A1, A2, A3 I wanted but total or A1+A2+A3).  
Of course, I was able to show such mean of a read if the graph is NOT stacked (by stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", width = 0.7,).  But I was wondering if I can show the mean of ALL reads in a same plot : (

Comment: I believe the blue area you specified is becoming the total of A1, A2, and A3 (not the mean) is because you're also specifying to plot the points of `number` based on its exact (not averaged) value. Your y-axis can either be the mean of A1, A2, and A3 (so blue area of A bar equals 15 but you lose your `number` legend), or the blue area can be the total of A1, A2, and A3 but you keep your `number` legend.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing for further alternatives.  I see in this case it will be for each replicate I suppose.  I'll talk with my group and see which visualization is most intuitive to understand in our context.